# Find all Users that bought their car before they were 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to find all Users that bought their car before they were 18.

I need a query like this:

```
User.includes(:car)
    .where(car: { bought_at < (user.birthday + 18.years)})
```

**How can I write such an query in Rails 5 with Postgresql?** Thank you

Comment: `User.joins(:car).where('cars.bought_at <  users.birthday + 18.years')` should work.

Comment: `User.includes(:car).where('cars.bought_at < users.birthday + INTERVAL "18 years"')` in postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the following

```
User.includes(:car).where( 'cars.bought_at < ?', user.birthday + 18.years)
```

Make sure the database columns `bought_at` and `birthday` are `DateTime` format.

Hope to help